# Can women wear silk outside of the house? If the silk clothes are not decorated?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia

can women wear colorful clothes outside of the home? if women cover themselves adequately.

Comment: And why not? Woman are by default permitted to wear silk.

Comment: Actually, silk is shiny and eye-catching fabric so I wanted to get some people's opinion that a woman wearing silk outside of the house is this permitted or not.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, silk is permissible to wear outside. However, when it comes to the to the clothes (silk or not) I believe it is permissible depending on the intention. The reasoning why is that you can wear colorful clothes and those are eye-catching. Just make sure your intention is not to capture the attention of the opposite gender. Of course if the clothing is over the top (excessive beauty) and for sure will catch everyone's attention then it would fall under the same impressibility such as wearing heavy make up or wearing perfume when passing by men.